# Implementing Interface and using Class object instead of Interface object

Tags: java

I have the interface `TestInterface` and the class `TestClass`.

`TestClass` now implements this interface. However, I would like to pass a `TestClass` object as a parameter for method.

Here, however, an error is displayed to me.

Why is that?

I thought I could use an object that implements the interface wherever an object of the interface can be used.

How do I change the program?

```
public interface TestInterface {
    int v=0;
    public void method(TestInterface t);
}
```

```
public class TestClass implements TestInterface{
    int v = 5;
    public void method(TestClass t) {
        v=10;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting?  (The root cause is likely the confusion that you can't define variables in interfaces -- or, you can, but they don't do what you expect them to -- but the appropriate fix will depend on the exact error.)

Comment: When you override a method, you cannot make the types of the parameters *more* specific. Imagine a scenario (assume this compiles without error) where you have a variable `foo` of type `TestInterface` (which is actually a `TestClass`) and another `TestInterface` object `bar` (which is not a `TestClass` instance) and you call `foo.method(bar)`. Your code wouldn't work then, because TestClass's `method` method requires a `TestClass`, even though `TestInterface` is fine with any `TestInterface`

Comment: Also note that you can only make static variables in interfaces, and even if `TestInterface` was a class, the `v` from the superclass would get shadowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because that violates the contract of the interface: the method is supposed to accept any implementation of `TestInterface`, not specifically instances of `TestClass`. Instead, you can use a type parameter in the interface to restrict the parameter types.

```
public interface TestInterface<T extends TestInterface<T>> {
    int v=0;
    public void method(T t);
}
public class TestClass implements TestInterface<TestClass>{
    int v = 5;
    public void method(TestClass t) {
        v=10;   
    }
}
```